# Why do I get <built-in method title of str object at 0x7fb554f9f238> instead of the value ?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to retrieve the title attribute from book_title but I get `<built-in method title of str object at 0x7fb554f9f238>` instead. I have passed the book_title as a parameter to the route book and have assigned the respective value of book_title in booktitle.html

Here, is my route

```
@app.route('/search/<title>/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def btitle(title):
    book_title = db.execute("SELECT title,author,isbn from books WHERE (title LIKE :title)",params={"title":title}).fetchall()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        book_title = db.execute("SELECT title,author,isbn from books WHERE (title LIKE :title)",params={"title":title}).fetchall()
        if book_title:
            return render_template("booktitle.html",book_title=book_title)
        else:
            return render_template("error.html")
    else:
        book_title = db.execute("SELECT title,author,isbn from books WHERE (title LIKE :title)",params={"title":title}).fetchall()
        if book_title:
            return redirect(url_for("book",book_title=book_title))



@app.route('/books/<book_title>/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def book(book_title):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("individualbook.html",book_title=book_title)
```

And, these are the html pages for `booktitle.html` and `individualbook.html`

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    {{ book }}
    {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Search results</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for book in book_title %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url_for('book', book_title=book_title) }}">
                {{ book.title }} 


            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

`individualbook.html`

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Book
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Book Details</h1>

    <ul>

        <li>Title: {{ book_title.title }}</li>
        <li>author: {{ book_title.author }}</li>
        <li>isbn: {{ book_title.isbn }}</li>

    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

When I try to get `title` ,`author` and `isbn` values I get `Title:<built-in method title of str object at 0x7fb554f9f238>` and `author` and `isbn` values are empty.

Comment: You're not using any kind of ORM; the thing you get back from your call to `db.execute()` is just a list of tuples, it's not an object with field attributes. `title` just happens to also be the name of a method on the string class.

Comment: So how do I solve this problem ?

Comment: book_title is just a string and doesn't have built-in methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have just put | book_title.title |,
but it should be | book_title.title() |.
I guess it will work when you put the parenthesis...

Answer (score 0):

- in route `app.btitle` the `book_title` variable passed to `render_template` is explicitly assigned database response objects which might respond to attribute resolution correctly
- in route `app.book` (individualbook.html), `book_title` is an argument of the function/route set by framework based on request data and route annotation. Such variable is type of `str` and don't have any attributes of `.author` or `.isbn`. The coincidence here is, that python3 `str` has a `title` method (see `pydoc3 str.title`) and hence the unexpected output in the template.